# Marklogic Structured Query Definition

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using structured query to fetch 100k messages from the database as below:

```
sqb.and(
          sqb.word(sqb.jsonProperty(status.name), toBeReported.name),
          sqb.word(sqb.jsonProperty(dataCategory.name), param.businessCategory),
          sqb.range(sqb.jsonProperty(creationDate.name), marklogicDateFormat.name, Operator.LE, DateUtil.printFpmlDateTime(param.messagesTime)))
```

then, applying the sorting on it using optionsName.

I am getting timeout error sometimes like :

```
SVC-EXTIME: search-impl:apply-search($querydef) -- Time limit exceeded
```

Can someone please tell me that are structured queries make unfiltered searched or filtered searched? can we make structured queries to make unfiltered searched?

Answer (score 1):

Is the query trying to retrieve all 100k messages in a single request?

The recommended approach is to paging over the result list, getting somewhere between 100 and 1,000 documents (the sweet spot can vary depending on the document size and other factors) in each request and processing each response page concurrently with requesting the next page for optimal throughput.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: I am retrieving the messages in the batch of 1000 records. So after it fetched around 50k records, I get this exception

Comment: Is the query running within a multi-statement transaction?  If so, a better approach is to run a point-in-time query.  If you provide the code that's executing the search and not just the query, someone might be able to offer more useful suggestions.